# ES6 add css class in class method

Tags: css, es6-class

How can I add css class to instance of this class in isCompleted method? I tried something like this, but it's not working?

```
class Task {
    constructor(title, description) {
        this._title = title;
        this._description = description;
    }

    addToList () {
        let tasksList = document.getElementById('tasksList');
        let task = document.createElement('li');
        task.setAttribute('class', 'task');

        let taskTitle = document.createElement('h3');
        taskTitle.setAttribute('class', 'task__title');
        taskTitle.innerText = this._title;

        let taskDescription = document.createElement('p');
        taskDescription.setAttribute('class', 'task__description');
        taskDescription.innerText = this._description;

        task.appendChild(taskTitle);
        task.appendChild(taskDescription);
        tasksList.appendChild(task);
    };

    isCompleted(){
         this.classList.add('task-completed');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does _this_ refer to? ... I mean, a DOM element can have a class set using `classList.add()`

Comment: at the beginnig I want to apologize - I'm the beginner. I want to create TODO app. I have the html form and after submit this form I create new Task(). Now I want do something like this: each task have checkbox and when it be checked I want to add css class 'task-completed' to this particular task

Comment: Well, you can't add a CSS class to a Task or an ES6 class. The `classList.add()` works pretty much the same as `setAttribute('class', '...')` does